# How to create the vertical menu and make the submenu on the menu's right side in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

As the picture show, how can I create the menu like that in WPF?

I've tried that by using Popup control and Menus control, but the effect is not ideal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do two things:

1. Set Menu.ItemsPanel to StackPanel
2. Change the **Popup's Placement** of MenuItems from Bottom to Right. I just right-clicked on the MenuItem in visual studio designer and picked EditTempalate from context menu. In the template I found popup control and changed the placement to Right. It works nice

Final xaml:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle1}">
        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 2" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 3" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sub item 4" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 3" />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 4" />
</Menu>
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what i want ! Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question, when i picked EditTemplate from context menu, it generated a lot of lines of code automatically. I just want to change the Popup's Placement value and I don't want Xaml contains many lines of code. How can I do this simply? Thank you!

Comment: Please can you show more detail. I don't see any popup placement value.It doesn't make me sense.

Comment: You need to edit menuitem template. In my code it is defined in the style MenuItemStyle1 which I have not included, since it can be generated by visual studio. Google for wpf edit template

Comment: @Liero I have used your code, and when long words - the text is partly hidden. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this menu using ToggleButton and Popup.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToggleButton Content="Home"   Name="ToggleButton1" Foreground="Black"  Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsOpen,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=Popup1}" ClickMode="Press"/>
    <ToggleButton Content="Controls" Grid.Row="1"   Name="ToggleButton2" Foreground="Black"  Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsOpen,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=Popup2}" ClickMode="Press"/>

    <Popup VerticalAlignment="Top"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton1}" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Popup1" Placement="Right" IsOpen="False"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <Grid Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="300" Height="300">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="Xaml"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Routed Events"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Visual Tree"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>

    <Popup VerticalAlignment="Top"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton2}" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Popup2" Placement="Right" IsOpen="False"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <Grid Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="300" Height="300">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="Xaml"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Routed Events"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Visual Tree"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use `MenuItem.ItemsPanel`

for example

```
<Menu>
<Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Menu.ItemsPanel>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use the Expander control.

Comment: I've tried to set <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/> , it can make the menu vertical, but it can't make the submenu right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the PopupMenu control man. No need for changing the items panel.

Comment: What's the  PopupMenu control? Is about the DevExpress ?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. The ContextMenu class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu(v=vs.110).aspx).