# Create a vertical Menu with subitem in Wpf

Tags: wpf, menu

I want to created a vertical Menu in Wpf.

I've tried the following code:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

    <Menu.ItemsPanel Header="Setting">
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
</Menu>
```

This creates a vertical menu, but sub-menus will be opened at the bottom of the main menu. I want them to be opened in the left side instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create the vertical menu and make the submenu on the menu's right side in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977828/how-to-create-the-vertical-menu-and-make-the-submenu-on-the-menus-right-side-in)